# adding drivers to WinPE v4(win8 version) for NVME PCIe SSD

Tags: windows, drivers, nvme

We have this specific iso that when mounted on a device with m.2 NVME drive it cannot detect it, and as such we cannot use it for its perpuses. We do not have support for this as such we cant get the newer version of the BMR iso that supports nvme. Is there a way to install drivers to this ISO so that it can detect the nvme drive??

The iso is the Bacula WinBMR 3.4.2
it can detect sata drives normally.

Also this is not an issue of AHCI vs RAID mode on the bios. This has been tested.

Comment: What's your question? How to add drivers to WinPE?

Comment: The WinMBR is an enterprise feature so documentation is very good hidden behind contacting sales rep, so i would contact bacula. Maybe you can elaborate a bit on your use case so wr can think with you about alternatives

Comment: I would strongly disagree about the provided documentation from bacula. It literally says in the documentation that we have from them to google the process of adding pre-boot drivers on the BMR ISO. I have found a way to add drivers to the boot.wim file of the iso using DISM from cmd. Yet any driver that i add to the wim and any configuration that i use on the BIOS (ACHi or RAID) in unable to detect the NVME m.2 drive on the system. This also causes the BMR script that runs in the ISO to break . So i am asking if there is a better way to integrate the drivers into the ISO and detect the drive.

Comment: I didn't found any documentation. But dism is indeed the right way. Where did you found that?

Comment: i figured it out myself, as the only way to modify a PE image with drivers on boot is with DISM. The problem is that  dont know what are the extact drivers needed for this. After some more "digging" i found that the version of PE that bacula uses for this is based on WIndows 8, which if google and microsoft are to be considered, doesnt have native NVME support as an OS it needs to be upgraded to 8.1 for that.

Comment: So my course of action so far is to find either the specific driver for the machine that i am currently using (chipset raid controller NVME specific driver etc) or find a way to "Upgrade the image" so that it can natively support NVME drives. Note that this problem is also apparent for newer integrated NIC's intel or otherwise. Even if i manage to read then NVME with the iso , then i will need to use a eth to usb adapter that from testing always works to procced with the restore process, as it all hapens over TCP/ip